# Which PayPal API method starts a virtual terminal session?

Tags: paypal, terminal

I want to start a virtual terminal session on PayPal from my site so that I can pass various account and transaction information automatically.

I've looked through the PayPal API but nothing seems to be relevant.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an API for specifically connecting to the Virtual Terminal in the account.  What you would want to use if you are wanting to create a similar interface, would be to use the DoDirectPayment API and create a user interface similar to that of the Virtual Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The new REST APIs also offer credit card sale functionality.

Comment: It does but it does not support same fields as Virtual Terminal. For example i found out that its not possible to populate "Item Name/Item Title" field within paypal export using REST APIs